# How can an authenticated user upload a file to S3 on an iWatch with Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, amazon-s3, aws-mobilehub

I have an iPhone app with a Watchkit Extensions. I am managing my users with AWS mobile hub. The user logs into the iPhone and the WatchKit app collects data that I want to later upload to a protected bucket for the authenticated user.

I want the user's data to be protected as well as uploaded from cell data if possible which would require me to skip transferring any files or sending queued messages to iPhone before upload to S3.

How can I upload a protected/private file to S3 from an iWatch over cell data?

Comment: Thats too broad of a question. Your extension should ideally interact with your parent app, which should in-turn be doing API calls.

Comment: @Annjawn, I know the apple watch can make API calls while away from the iPhone using cell data. I was hoping that there would be a solution to install the AWS sdk for s3 and authentication to the watch and some how transfer the auth tokens to allow the watch to work in isolation to allow my users to be away from their phone. Is this impossible or just highly regarded as not recommended?